# Get the shared library name from a function in the library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

In linux, Is there a way to get the shared library name from one of its functions (or from any static library functions linked to it).

Basically, wanted to check if there is an API/variable available similar to `program_invocation_short_name/program_invocation_name` that is currently available for processes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if there is a dynamic symbol named `"foo"`, use [`dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "foo")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to find out the address of such symbol, or `NULL` if there is no such dynamic symbol.

I don't know why you'd care about the shared library name, though.

When you have the address of a symbol, you can always read the [`/proc/self/maps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) pseudofile to find out which binary the symbol originates from. (If the symbol is in an `r--` mapping, it is an immutable contant, like a string literal for example.  If it is in an `r-x` mapping, it is in code, probably a function. It if is in an `rw-` mapping, it is a global variable.) Do note that because it is a pseudofile, it is part of the kernel binary interface, and never localized.

Comment: The reason is i want to log the  list of the libraries loaded and the duration for which they are loaded in the process. Looks like i should manage with the /proc filesystem

Comment: @MSK: For that, you probably should look into the [`dl_iterate_phdr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) function. Duration is almost always the lifetime of the process, except for libraries loaded by the application via `dlopen()` and closed via `dlclose()`. To detect those, I recommend running the process via `ltrace -e dlopen ./program...`. In general, to find out which files the process accesses, use `strace -e trace=open ./program...`. `ldd ./program` will tell you which dynamic libraries will be loaded before `main()` is run.